# Laravel 8 Cookie -> Can't get cookie value

Tags: laravel, cookies

I have annoying problem that I can't fix for hours. Have been trying all google suggestions, so far nothing.

Function for setting/getting cookie right now:

```
        /* Check if user is logged in or else take cookie */

    if(Auth::check()){
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    }else{
        if(Cookie::get('user_id') !== null){
            $user_id_cookie = Cookie::get('user_id');
        }else{
            $user_id = Cookie::forever('user_id', Str::random(15));
            $user_id_cookie = $user_id;
        }

    }

    /* Check if user is logged in or else take cookie */
```

Cookie is set, but it doesn't get value back to blade.

For getting cookie value I have tried multiple solutions, for example 2:

```
$old = Crypt::decryptString(request()->cookie('user_id'))
$cookie_value = explode("|",$old)[1];
```

Or (As I have another cookie made in same way, and it's working. But I have no idea, why..)

```
  $old= Crypt::decrypt(Cookie::get('user_id'), false);
  $cookie_value = substr($old, 41);
```

But all these solutions shows this error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException
> The payload is invalid.

Comment: try this simple laravel way `$request->cookie('name')`

Comment: cookie method is an instance of  `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

Comment: the `EncryptCookies` middleware will encrypt and decrypt the cookies for you, there shouldn't be anything for you to decrypt at the point you get the value of the cookie